# Prestashop: slow back office, but fast in debug mode

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.7.7, and since a few weeks, I'm experiencing a really slow back office (10 to 20seconds between pages). I have no issues with the front office.
I upgraded to a faster server (doubled the CPU/RAM), but nothing changed.

Trying to know which module or hook could be responsible for this slowness, I enabled debug mode to have timings on the request. And in debug mode, the back office is super fast. I don't have the same issue at all.

I already tried to clear the 'prod' and 'dev' cache, my smarty recompilation settings are on "never recompile".

I'm a bit clueless right now, do you have an idea what could case such a difference between debug and prod modes ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, disabling cache (last section of BO advanced preference) make the site alot faster.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is in backoffice only, the smarty cache should not have anything to do with it.

My advice is to enable built-in profiler tool.

Open **/config/defines.inc.php** search for :

```
define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);
```

and set it to **true** and reload slow pages so you can have a visual report on the bottom of slow queries and/or operations that can impact the loading time of the pages.